# Needing to change and add interval to each line in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

### I have a govt contract.  They cannot share the information in a table.  I have to send them scripts to change the name in each line for a specific column and add number a the end.
Example:
Column - Name (NVARCHAR MAX)
John Doe
Steve Day

Needs to be changed to
Abc Name 1
Abc Name 2

Trick is, they cannot tell me the original value and cannot tell me how many names there are in the table, so the script would need to change the first line and add the next digit in line for each line after.

Advice appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can you even mock up some example data to show the source and expected results? (Full table rows, not just a single column data). Your question is not easy to follow. After a second read through of the question, I think you want to use a `ROW_NUMBER` function to add a number to column data.

```
UPDATE [table_name]
SET [column1] = [column1] + ' ' + CAST(mod.row_num as nvarchar)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [primary_key]
        , [column1]
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY [column1]) AS row_num
    FROM [table_name]
) AS mod
WHERE [table_name].primary_key = mod.primary_key;
```